# where can i find "pwdAccountLockedTime" in Apache-DS LDAP?

Tags: ldap, apacheds

I do right-click and choose "Fetch->Fetch operational attributes" but there is no `pwdAccountLockedTime` in attribute list. Where can i find `pwdAccountLockedTime`?

The Apache information is windows Apache Directory Studio(Version: 2.0.0.v20161101-M12)

Comment: The Apache information is windows Apache Directory Studio(Version: 2.0.0.v20161101-M12).

Comment: I try to add "ads-pwdAccountLockedTime" on attribute list, but it show "Waring! According to the schema attribute ads-pwdAccountLockedTime is not allowed." error message.

Comment: It may only be there if the account is actually locked. But you need to make up your mind as to whether you are talking about `pwdAccountLockedTime`, as per your question, or `ads-pwdAccountLockedTime` as per your comments.

Comment: yes, there is one account actually locked.

in Apache "Password Policy for LDAP Directories draft-behera-ldap-password-policy-10.txt" chapter 5.3.
The password policy option is defined as the following:
pwd-<passwordAttribute>

in my options:
"pwdAccountLockedTime" is passwordAttribute,
password policy option is "ads-pwdAccountLockedTime".

i think should add "ads-pwdAccountLockedTime" on attribute list.

Comment: So what does `ads-pwdAccountLockedTime` have to do with the price of fish? And how is your response consistent with 'the system is using ApacheDS'?

Comment: system using ApacheDS and Apache Directory Studio,i can't not change to use the OpenLDAP.@Esteban share a way to setting password policy, but it looks can not work at my system.

Comment: So which is it? What are you asking about? `pwdAccountLockedTime` or `ads-pwdAccountLockedTime`? You won't get `pwdAccountLockedTime` out of Apache-DS, but you might get `ads-pwdAccountLockedTime` if you have it configured correctly. Clarity please.

Comment: @Peggy I already mentioned in a comment that I had edited my answer with information concerning Apache DS. Which is just add the `ads-pwdAccountLockedTime` objectClass. See my edit with the documentation for configuration of the password policy for ApacheDS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT : `ads-pwdAccountLockedTime` hinted that you use Apache Directory Server, the documentation to configure [password policy is here](http://directory.apache.org/apacheds/advanced-ug/4.3-password-policy.html)

You have to add the objectClass `ads-passwordPolicy` to be able to use the attributes on your entry

--

Apache Directory Studio is just a client which fetches informations from a directory.

If you want to see the attribute, then the directory must have it stored.

If you get `"Warning! According to the schema attribute ads-pwdAccountLockedTime is not allowed."` it's probably because you did not include the schema needed for the password policy to work properly or simply did not enabled the password policy (assuming you're using OpenLDAP)

To do so, you need to enabled the `ppolicy` overlay and configure it correctly, which requires you to add the `ppolicy.schema`.

See : http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/overlays.html and http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch6/ppolicy.html

Comment: You have to add the object class you named for the *server* to be able to use those attributes, which would be accomplished by loading the appropriate schema.

Comment: Thanks for sharing OpenLDAP setting Password policy , But the system is using ApacheDS. >"<

Comment: @Peggy So your question and tags should have said so.

Comment: i add a new Attribute (Attribute type "passwordPolicy" and other option "ads-passwordPolicy"). It still show "Waring! According to the schema attribute passwordPolicy;ads-passwordPolicy is not allowed." error message.